# Annotations: when is arrayOf needed

Tags: kotlin

Lets say we have a Java annotation  as follows:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Hans {
    String[] value() default {};
}
```

In Kotlin I am allowed to use the Annotation as follows:

```
@Hans(value = "test")
```

As soon as i change the property name from 'value' to 'name' it is not allowed to use this syntax anymore, instead I need to have arrayOf(..).

```
@Hans(name = arrayOf("test"))
```

Is that a bug or a design decision and if so what is the reason behind it.

Many thanks in advance
Kind regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. Java treats the `value` annotation specially and allows to omit the annotation parameter name when you use it. Kotlin follows this special treatment and also allows you to omit the parameter name, allowing you to write `@Hans("test")`. Supporting this syntax for array parameters requires to treat the parameter as `vararg`, so Kotlin does that and allows you to omit the `arrayOf`.